# Find a file and navigate his folder in CMD windows

Tags: windows, cmd

i need to navigate to a .exe file that's i don't know the path

i'm using dir *.exe /s to find the file, and it works, but after it find i need to do a cd to navigate for this file folder.

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dir /s /b *.exe` to get a one-line-output of the filename including the complete path.

Best way to get that output into a variable is a `for` Loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b *.exe') do set "exefile=%%A"
```

To get the path of the file only, use the `for` modifiers:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b *.exe') do set "exepath=%%~dpA"
```

Note: this works in batchfiles. For use at the command prompt use a single `%` only (`%A` instead of `%%A`)

If there are several matches, the `set` command will be executed for each of them, resulting in overwriting the variable and give you the last one in the end.

See `for /?` for further explanations.

To change the working directory: `cd "%exepath%"` or `pushd "%exepath%"`. Of course you can also put one of this commands directly after `do` instead of the `set` command  (not creating a variable)